# Would North Korean aircraft be able to fly international routes?

Tags: internal-consistency, law

Theoretically if North Korea could produce safe passenger aircraft could it be certified to fly on international routes?

I don't care about the program cost or the required engineering effort, that would be part of my story, I just want to know would it be legal to fly it on international routes.

Comment: Welcome to the site, CakesOrPearls. Please note that we encourage users to conduct research prior to asking questions. Additionally, the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to fictional worlds or alternate Earths. if you could [edit] your post to indicate how this applies to a fictional world, this may avoid being put on hold to await such clarification.

Comment: They aren't yet on such strong embargo. Also China wouldn't even let it. It is also questionable, how useful would it be. All their contact what they make with the external world, is a work against their isolationism. A more useful strategy is to put them on economical pressure, but allowing and even encouraging all their contacts with the rest of the humanity.

Answer (score 3):

It already does

[Air Koryo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Koryo)

> Air Koryo (Chosŏn'gŭl: 고려항공; MR: Koryŏ Hanggong; formerly 조선민항; Chosŏn Minhang) is the state-owned national flag carrier airline of North Korea, headquartered in Sunan-guyŏk, Pyongyang. Based at Pyongyang Sunan International Airport (IATA: FNJ), it operates international scheduled and charter services to points in Asia.
>
> Air Koryo has offices in Beijing and Shenyang, China; Vladivostok, Russia; Bangkok, Thailand and Berlin, Germany. There are sales agencies in Tokyo, Japan; Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia; Kuwait; Singapore; Taipei, Taiwan; Hong Kong; Italy; Austria and Germany.

Even though the aircraft themselves are Russian-made (Antonov, Ilyushin, and Tupolev), there's no real reason (beyond economics) that North Korean aircraft couldn't be used.